# How do I make one component talk to another when they are generated with .map() in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple components with the same module using `map()`.

```
   list.map((data, index) => <MyComponent key={index} value={d}/>)
```

Then `<p>` in each of MyComponent changes colors from green to red when it is clicked.

```
const MyComponent = ({value}) => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const buttonOnClick = () => {
        setClicked(true);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <p style={clicked ? {color: 'green'} : {color: 'red'}}>{value}</p>
            <button onClick={buttonOnClick}>click</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

In this case, I would like to turn color of `<p>` in other MyComponent red when one of them are clicked.

How can I check the `<p>` state of other MyComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback into your child component, and have your parent component to store and control the state. Here's an example:

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3];

const MyComponent = ({ value, clickedValue, onClick }) => {
  const style = { color: clickedValue === value ? 'green' : 'red' };
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={style}>{value}</p>
      {/* Callback with the value */}
      <button onClick={() => onClick(value)}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [clickedValue, setClickedValue] = React.useState();
  
  const handleClick = value => {
    setClickedValue(value);
  };
    
  return React.Children.toArray(
    list.map(value => (
      <MyComponent
        value={value}
        clickedValue={clickedValue}
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    ))
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. How should I manage each component's state if I want to update unselected components red color while keeping selected one green? Should I use array to track state of each component?

Comment: I see, maybe you should callback with an ID? so each component can cross-check that ID to do more dynamic result

Comment: @DPark I have updated my answer, can you check and see

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to revise comment! It was really helpful to understand how the logic works. :)

Comment: @DPark no worries! Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest option would be to lift state up into the parent component: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html